# Extracting data from a matrix based on second longitude and latitude matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

I have two matrices, one contains data about samples collected (each row represents a sample and the columns different pieces of information for that sample e.g. longitude and latitude where it was collected) and the other contains particular points of interest (one column contains latitude and the other longitude with each row being a point of interest).

For example points of interest may be:

```
[-64.7664,
 -64.2296,
 -64.4314,
 -64.4869,
 -64.400,
 -64.4000;

 117.3117,
 127.9522,
 127.9867,
 128.10270,
 127.13330,
 127.13330]
```

Where column one represents latitude and column 2 represents longitude.

Whereas the sample data will look something like:

```
c1   c2   c3   c4   c5        c6        c7    ...
0,   3,   6,   4,   -74.21,   103,      4     ...
1,   NaN, 4,   6,   -70.1,    101,      8     ...
3,   0,   5,   3,   -64.7664, 117.3117, 5     ...
2,   4,   12,  NaN, -62.1,    120,      NaN   ...
19,  5,   16,  1,   -64.400,  127.1333, 16    ...
```

Data continues for another 29 columns. In this example, row three, and 5 would be needed to be made into a new matrix.

I need to find which samples are at these particular interest points (so the longitude and latitude of the sample is the same as one of the rows of the data containing the particular points of interest).

How do I go about finding which samples (rows) were collected at the points of interest and then create a new matrix containing only the information of the samples found at the points of interest?

Comment: Some example would be useful.

Comment: can you show us some of your matices and your expected result in code?

Comment: an example has been added thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect` like in this example

```
a = [1 2; 3 4; 5 5];
b = [3 4; 5 5; 2 1];

[c,ia,ib] = intersect(a,b,'rows')
```

where the vectors `ia` contains the common indexes for `a` and `ib` the common indexes in `b`.

Comment: I had already tried this but it doesn't work. My assumption as to why it doesn't work is because the points of interest matrix only has two columns while the other matrix has 38 with longitude and latitude being the 6th and 7th row. I don't know if that is in fact why, that is just an assumption.

Comment: You can choose the column of interest, for instance `a(:,[1 2])` and `b(:,[25 32])`

Comment: `intersect` is the way to go. But probably there is a mixup between columns and rows in your example and description of the data.

Comment: The column and rows are in the right place, I did figure out the problem though. The problem is that some samples have the exact same longitude and latitude as another sample and this only tells me the row of one of the samples of that longitude and latitude, not the several that share the same location

Comment: how would I go about dealing with this?